# Is there a common name for products of intervals and disks?

Tags: geometry, terminology

To be precise I mean subsets of Euclidean spaces

$[0,1]^n\times\Pi_{i=1\dots m} D_i^2\subset \mathbb{R}^{(n+2m)}$

where the $D_i^2$ are 2-dimensional disks.  This could be called a product of an $n$-cube with a polydisk.  But I wonder if there is a shorter name.  I note the term *polycylinder* means something else:

http://docs.techsoft3d.com/visualize/3df/21/2113/Hoops3DGS/prog_guide/02_16_geometry_cylinders.html